# Python: How to remove comma number separator in numbers from imported csv file

Tags: python, csv, type-conversion

I have imported a csv file as a dictionary, it goes simething like this

```
dict1 = {'key1': ['0', '0', '100'], 'key2': ['0', '0', '2,000']}
```

I now need to convert the dictionary values into integers in order to perform some calculations

```
dict1_int = dict((key, [int(element) for element in value]) for key, value in dict1.items())
```

It appears that the number separator commas in numbers like "2,000" is preventing the integer conversion. How can I remove just that kind of commas, and not the commas separating the value elements? I am stuck with vanilla python, so cannot use anything like pandas. Thank you in advance!

Edit: How the csv file is imported

```
with open('file.csv') as file: 
  reader = csv.reader(file) 
  next(reader, None) 
  for rows in reader: 
    data = [rows[1], rows[2], rows[3]] 
    dict1[rows[0]] = data
```

Comment: How did you import it?  As long as you know which columns should be integers, just do `f.replace(',','')` on those fields.

Comment: this is how i imported it:
```
with open('file.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader, None)
    for rows in reader:
        data = [rows[1], rows[2], rows[3]]
        dict1[rows[0]] = data
```
I would need to remove commas from values in all columns. I am messing around with file.replace but is unsure how it works with dictionary. if you have a better way to import the file and do this I am all ears

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69903650/edit) your question to include your import code.  Comments don't display multi-line code correctly, esp. for Python.

Comment: Thank you, i will edit it in, had to leave right after last comment so couldn't look at it

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1 = {'key1': ['0', '0', '100'], 'key2': ['0', '0', '2,000']}

dict1_int = dict((key, [int(str(element).replace(',', '')) for element in value]) for key, value in dict1.items())

print(dict1_int)
```

Answer:
{'key1': [0, 0, 100], 'key2': [0, 0, 2000]}

Comment: Thank you for your help. If you don't mind me verbalizing it to better understand, your code convert each element into string, and then replace ',' with '', and after that it is converted into integer, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

If ALL of the non-key the columns are integers, it's easy, and you might as well convert to integer at the same time:

```
with open('file.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader, None)
    for rows in reader:
        data = [int(r.replace(',','')) for r in rows[1:]]
        dict1[rows[0]] = data
```

Comment: I appreciate that, you also showed me that [1:] can refers to all elements from index 1 onwards, thank you!